# Unable to create project from archetype [org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE->]

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a simple Maven project in Eclipse Luna. I am trying to create a simple web project using the Artifact Id spring-webmvc 4.0.5.RELEASE.

Now, when I click finish it's giving me the following error...

[Spring_mvc_err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHevi.png)

I thought, may this arctifact id does not exist in my Eclipse Luna, therefore search google for this artifact id and found this url:
[Spring Web MVC](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.5.RELEASE)

Any idea, how i can add this artifact id in my eclipse IDE.

Comment: The error is quite clear. You are using a dependency as an archetype which is a different beast.

Comment: @M.Deinum, ok, my mistake. How should i reslove this issue, i want to create a basic Spring MVC Application from the archetype 'maven-archetype-webapp', and then add spring-webmvc dependency in pom.xml file

Comment: If you are about to use Spring Boot I suggest to use https://start.spring.io/

Answer (score 0):

i have managed to create and successfully deploy (on web server) the basic spring MVC application for the archetype 'maven-archetype=webapp', using following command on command-line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.wiley.beginningspring -DartifactId=basic -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp -DinteractiveMode=false
```

I've managed to resolve my issue by following this link https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html